# How to understand decoding HTTP Requests at Client side?

Tags: c, http-headers, zlib

I am working with [zLib](https://github.com/madler/zlib/), and my goal is to decode the data sent to my server. I am trying to understand how to go about doing this.

Assume I have an HTTP Request Headers (just off the top of my head):

```
Referer: http://google.com\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
\r\n
ENCODED_DATA
```

Using the content extracted from within `Accept-Encoding:` header.

Assume `Ctx = ENCODED_DATA`

Does this tell me that in order to retrieve the plain text `Ctx`, I need to apply `Gzip(Ctx)` and then `Deflate(Ctx)`?

Basically, the question is, how do I go about decoding the `ENCODED_DATA` inside the HTTP Request at client side assuming the headers are displayed as above.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would discourage you from writing your own web server, because you WILL introduce massive security bugs.  **Especially** if you don't understand the standard.

Second, the "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate" is the client telling the server *when you send the response*, it can be in either gzip or deflate format.  This has nothing to do with the "ENCODED_DATA" part of the request.

The data in the request is NOT gzip compressed unless the client also sends the "Content-Encoding:" header. (And that header will say "gzip" or "deflate"). From the request shown, your data is probably not compressed at all, but in "[www-form-urlencoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type)".

I'm going to flat out state that unless your goal is to learn the standards (in which case, you should be reading them, plus web server code), you should avoid playing at this layer at all costs. Just use one of the hundreds of web frameworks that do this job for you.

Comment: I am not writing a web server. Just a client, server side application for a local pipe server. Also, the data that I am getting from the HTTP request is not urlencoded, it contains malformed characters, and I'm almost 99% sure that it has something to do with the content-encoding. Any other ideas?

Comment: If you are writing the client, why did you set the Content-Type to url-encoded if you are not sending valid url-encoded data?  If you want the server to decode your data correctly, you have to tell it what you are sending.  I still am really unclear on what you are trying to do, or why, since you should be using libraries/frameworks to do this.